# Can a sink drain connect to toilet drain before toilet vent?

Tags: bathroom, drain, vent

[image]Long story short, I ran my bathroom sink drain, which has an AAV, into the toilet drain before the toilet drain vent. So the current drain goes: toilet -> sink (through a wye) -> vent for toilet -> washing machine drain (through another wye). Both the sink and washing machine will have AAVs. Did I mess up? I can still easily go back and fix it.

Comment: it depends where you live, is the toilet drain separate from gray water drain

Comment: It is not. Everything goes to the same place. I'm more concerned about venting issues.

Comment: What is the applicable plumbing code for your local area having jurisdiction (LAHJ)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got in touch with the building inspector. He said it would act as a wet vent, but didn't meet code for a wet vent. I ended up just redoing it per my original plan. I had changed it to the new idea on the fly because I forgot why I had planned to do it the other way (it was to have the drains enter the main after the main vent). New idea seemed more efficient (shorter pipe run, fewer turns to get to main). [image]